Little trouble understanding a uniqueness proof?
I'm reading Postnikov's Analytic Geometry. Here:



What is happening in there? I understand they may be somehow showing that $x$ is unique but I don't understand what is happening in the equations.

It is telling you: "If such a solution $x$ exists, then it must be of the form $x=b-a$. On the other hand, if $x=b-a$, then it is true that $a+x=b$. Therefore such $x$ exists and it's unique."

What happens is that the operation "vector subtraction" is defined.
At the start only vector addition and the additive inverse vector are available, directly from the axiom list of a vector space, the part that says that $(V,+)$ is an additive group. "additive" here means just a convention how the operation and especially the inverse is written $(-a)$ vs $a^{-1}$, it has no other meaning above that.
Of course it is important that the operation as function of two arguments has exactly one function value (that is then also compatible with its intended purpose).
